# Image not working - Is it a Chrome Bug?

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome, browser

I'm having an issue with chrome and I wanted to know if is a bug or my fault.

When I try to use an Image called `300x250.png` the tag IMG is stripped from the browser, this is not happening with the images with other filenames.

**HTML:**

```
<img src="300x250.png"> <!-- not working -->
<img src="300x25.png"> <!-- working -->
<img src="300x2500.png"> <!-- working -->
<img src="a300x250.png"> <!-- working -->
<img src="100x250.png"> <!-- working -->
```

Anyone have an explanation for that?

Comment: What do you mean, "the tag IMG is stripped from the browser"? How do you know this has happened?

Comment: Any kind of ad blocker installed? Some of them take “typical” ad image dimensions inside file names as criterion to block images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue of **Adblock** (not only in Chrome, the issue appears Firefox as well) affecting `300x250` sized images as well as possibly affecting other specifically sized images too (at least in the Firefox version) - see the easylist section below.

The reasoning behind it is that because `300x250` is a standard ad size, therefore it is automatically blocked by adblock. You can confirm this by turning adblock off - you should now see the image appear.

I've found a [**easylist here for the Firefox version**](https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt), and it shows multiple types of dimensions that would get an image blocked (such as `300x250`, `468x60` etc.), and I'm guessing the Chrome version wouldn't be too dissimilar.

The only fixes to this problem are either slightly tweak the image dimensions or you could simply turn adblock off.

See bugs [**Issue 7387**](https://code.google.com/p/adblockforchrome/issues/detail?id=7387) and [**Issue 7390**](https://code.google.com/p/adblockforchrome/issues/detail?id=7390) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

as my friend said , maybe you have installed a adBlocker ! but i myself think the address isn't correct ; change the file name . or maybe the format of image (png) isn't correct ! check these ...